# I can not run xdebug in xampp server with eclipse?

Tags: yii, xdebug

Deal all,

I am new babe in php, and I am working yii framework.for the server,I use xampp (PHP Version 5.4.22) and the eclipse to write code, now I want to debug on eclipse by xdebug and I have open some lines in php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

after I have breakpoint and run debug in eclipse, it run this url:

```
http://localhost/ktbeauty/themes/classic/views/admin/login.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=13918210553298
```

and the page shows like that:

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22
```

Can you tell me what it is wrong ?and How Can I fix to run xdebug in xampp with eclipse?

thankyou very much

Comment: I have checked inforinfo and it show the debug already here "with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans"

Comment: How about using PHP-console yii extension with chrome addon? http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/php-console/